# Why do I have to enable 'Developer' for Spotlight to find Numbers documents?

Tags: spotlight, bug

In order to get macOS Spotlight to find Numbers documents, I need to enable "Developer" in Spotlight's settings.

Why do I need to do this? I don't want to enable developer searches from Spotlight, so I'm stuck being unable to use Spotlight to find Numbers documents.

---

(I'm [not the only person](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7189991) with this problem.)

Comment: Do you/Did you have Xcode installed?

Comment: @fsb: Yes I do.

Comment: I've read that your issue is the result of having Xcode and that's how Apple has decided to do it.  I'm not sure it can be changed.

Comment: @fsb: Can you provide a link. That sounds nuts. It means that in order to find my Numbers docs, I need to see quite a bit of developer hits. (Yet another reason to switch to Google!)

Comment: I'll have to look again, i closed that tab/browser because I'm shutting down for the night.  Try unchecking 'Developer' from Search Results for Spotlight in Settings.  See if that helps.  No promises, this is from memory :-).

Comment: @fsb: Thanks. I'm just kind of curious what their rational was if that's the case. (Unchecking Developer looses Numbers sheets.)